# Какие крутые инструменты предоставляет LLVM?

Tags: c++, c, clang, llvm

Я часто пользуюсь `calng`-ом (например для работы с `ast`), `clang-format` и `address-sanitizer` при работе, а какие еще клевые инструменты можно почерпнуть из `llvm`?

Comment: Sanitizer есть и в gcc, кстати, там список параметров намного шире, чем вы привели, в clange аналогично https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html или тут https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer жаль под win неработоспособен, но есть Dr. Memory на этот случай, аналог valgrind